# Como criar um socket no wildfly?

Tags: java, socket, websocket, wildfly

Preciso criar algo que leia tudo que chegue em uma porta específica e tratar essa informação.
É utilizado um servidor Ubuntu com WildFly 10 rodando.
As informações trafegadas são dos rastreadores (no caso é o CRX-1 da Concox e os da SunTech). Eles mandam uma String com as informações codificadas em hexadecimal. Tratar o dado é a parte fácil... não estou conseguindo ler a porta.

OBS.: Ao testar fora desse ambiente, com socket simples comum, o socket_cliente de teste conecta e transfere informação, quando está no wildFly ele não consegue conectar.

Tentei criar Web Socket... não obtive sucesso também...

Ultimo código que tentei, foi um web socket:

WSEndpoint.java (Peguei um de exemplo na net para testar)

```
package web_socket;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService;
import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

@ServerEndpoint("/vs_gateway")
@Stateless
public class WSEndpoint {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
    @Resource
    ManagedExecutorService mes;

    @OnMessage
    public String receiveMessage(String message, Session session) {
        log.info("Received : "+ message + ", session:" + session.getId());
        return "Response from the server";
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void open(Session session) {
        log.info("Open session:" + session.getId());
        final Session s = session;
        mes.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {             
                try {
                    for (int i=0;i
```

index.html (vindo do mesmo exemplo da internet para testar)

```
           
         var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9018/web_socket/vs_gateway");
         ws.onopen = function()
         {
            alert("Web Socket is connected!!");                 
         };
         ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
         {                  
            var msg = evt.data;
            alert("Message received:" +  msg);
         };
         ws.onclose = function()
         { 
            alert("Connection is closed..."); 
         };
```

OBS.: Nao consegui colocar o HTML... mas o lance eh o JS msm... 
O HTML eh o basico.. so o suficiente para a pagina abrir..

Comment: Adiciona o codigo do que vc tentou, as vezes tem um erro ;)

Comment: A porta do WildFly foi alterada de :8080 para :9018 la no [WildFly]/configuration/standalone.xml